# сортировка словарей по алфавиту

Tags: python

Здравствуйте!
Такой код:

```
def bina():
..
def main():
    bin = bina()
    for i in (bin):
        for j in pairs:
            if j in i['symbol']:
                a = i['Price'] 
                sor = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['Price'])
                print (sor)
```

написанный для получения определенных данных их  списка словарей и затем их сортировки выдает мне ошибку
string indices must be integers

Я хотел сортировать, как цифры по ключу "price",  так и значения по алфавиту по ключу "symbol".

В другом api вывод данных такой:

```
{'success': True, 'code': 'OK', 'msg': 'Operation succeeded.', 'timestamp': 1519816762838, 'data': [{'coinType': 'BTC', 'trading': True, 'symbol': 'BTC-USDT', 'lastDealPrice': 10578.99788, 'buy': 10578.997877, 'sell': 10578.99788, 'change': -10.00212, 'coinTypePair': 'USDT', 'sort': 100, 'feeRate': 0.001, 'volValue': 2695808.17452173, 'high': 11110.0, 'datetime': 1519816758000, 'vol': 252.11332126, 'low': 10458.999998, 'changeRate': -0.0009}, {'coinType': 'ETH', 'trading': True, 'symbol': 'ETH-BTC', 'lastDealPrice': 0.0815031, 'buy': 0.0815, 'sell': 0.0815031, 'change': -0.0007839, 'coinTypePair': 'BTC', 'sort': 100, 'feeRate': 0.001, 'volValue': 273.60462823, 'high': 0.08332097, 'datetime': 1519816758000, 'vol': 3331.102395, 'low': 0.08034008, 'changeRate': -0.0095}
```

Когда я выводил данные без pandas, то выделял данные по ключу 'data', затем опять выделял нужное мне.
С помощью примера с pandas ниже я получаю ошибку "'<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'"

Comment: сам словарь-то как выглядит?

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, как выглядит Ваш словарь, тогда мы сможем помочь.

Comment: {'symbol': 'RANO', 'Price': '0.00134460', 'Qty': '46.59000000'}
{'symbol': 'NANO', 'Price': '0.00001775', 'Qty': '20755.00000000'}
>>>

Comment: Вы из одного класса с @КириллВишняков ?

Comment: @aaasakurra, задайте новый вопрос! В нем укажите ваши данные на входе и то что вы хотите получить на выходе. PS не думаю, что можно построить решение, которое не зависит от структуры данных на входе...

Comment: добавил новый вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [93]: js_dict
Out[93]:
{'code': 'OK',
 'data': [{'buy': 10578.997877,
   'change': -10.00212,
   'changeRate': -0.0009,
   'coinType': 'BTC',
   'coinTypePair': 'USDT',
   'datetime': 1519816758000,
   'feeRate': 0.001,
   'high': 11110.0,
   'lastDealPrice': 10578.99788,
   'low': 10458.999998,
   'sell': 10578.99788,
   'sort': 100,
   'symbol': 'BTC-USDT',
   'trading': True,
   'vol': 252.11332126,
   'volValue': 2695808.17452173},
  {'buy': 0.0815,
   'change': -0.0007839,
   'changeRate': -0.0095,
   'coinType': 'ETH',
   'coinTypePair': 'BTC',
   'datetime': 1519816758000,
   'feeRate': 0.001,
   'high': 0.08332097,
   'lastDealPrice': 0.0815031,
   'low': 0.08034008,
   'sell': 0.0815031,
   'sort': 100,
   'symbol': 'ETH-BTC',
   'trading': True,
   'vol': 3331.102395,
   'volValue': 273.60462823}],
 'msg': 'Operation succeeded.',
 'success': True,
 'timestamp': 1519816762838}

In [94]: df = pd.DataFrame(js_dict['data'])

In [95]: df
Out[95]:
            buy     change  changeRate coinType coinTypePair       datetime  feeRate          high  lastDealPrice  \
0  10578.997877 -10.002120     -0.0009      BTC         USDT  1519816758000    0.001  11110.000000   10578.997880
1      0.081500  -0.000784     -0.0095      ETH          BTC  1519816758000    0.001      0.083321       0.081503

            low          sell  sort    symbol  trading          vol      volValue
0  10458.999998  10578.997880   100  BTC-USDT     True   252.113321  2.695808e+06
1      0.080340      0.081503   100   ETH-BTC     True  3331.102395  2.736046e+02
```

---

Правильно используя Pandas это можно сделать легко и быстро:

```
import pandas as pd

res = (pd.read_json('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker')
         .sort_values(['askPrice','symbol'])
         .to_dict('r'))
```

Результат (первые пять записей):

```
In [206]: res[:5]
Out[206]:
[{'askPrice': 0.0,
  'askQty': 0.0,
  'bidPrice': 0.0,
  'bidQty': 0.0,
  'symbol': '123456'},
 {'askPrice': 3.41e-06,
  'askQty': 609896.0,
  'bidPrice': 3.4e-06,
  'bidQty': 421500.0,
  'symbol': 'NCASHBTC'},
 {'askPrice': 3.54e-06,
  'askQty': 7806.0,
  'bidPrice': 3.53e-06,
  'bidQty': 49282.0,
  'symbol': 'IOSTBTC'},
 {'askPrice': 3.97e-06,
  'askQty': 183356.0,
  'bidPrice': 3.96e-06,
  'bidQty': 1544344.0,
  'symbol': 'TRXBTC'},
 {'askPrice': 4.93e-06,
  'askQty': 7201.0,
  'bidPrice': 4.92e-06,
  'bidQty': 10019.0,
  'symbol': 'TNBBTC'}]
```

---

если цену надо отсортировать по убыванию:

```
res = (pd.read_json('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker')
         .sort_values(['askPrice','symbol'], ascending=[0,1])
         .to_dict('r'))

In [208]: res[:5]
Out[208]:
[{'askPrice': 10689.96,
  'askQty': 0.0044,
  'bidPrice': 10683.94,
  'bidQty': 0.580227,
  'symbol': 'BTCUSDT'},
 {'askPrice': 1243.42,
  'askQty': 0.8633,
  'bidPrice': 1241.46,
  'bidQty': 0.02586,
  'symbol': 'BCCUSDT'},
 {'askPrice': 879.99,
  'askQty': 13.07867,
  'bidPrice': 879.5,
  'bidQty': 0.02213,
  'symbol': 'ETHUSDT'},
 {'askPrice': 218.75,
  'askQty': 4.15562,
  'bidPrice': 218.61,
  'bidQty': 44.38546,
  'symbol': 'LTCUSDT'},
 {'askPrice': 140.719,
  'askQty': 0.516,
  'bidPrice': 140.58,
  'bidQty': 0.094,
  'symbol': 'NEOUSDT'}]
```

Comment: Благодарю. С pandas получилось, когда сделал как здесь, изначально обращаться к api иным образом.

Comment: @aaasakurra, пардон, `no data - no help!` ;-)

Comment: Но теперь не выходит сделать то же самое с другим api, где вывод данных более сложный

Comment: как добавить код в комментарии?

Comment: @aaasakurra, добавить надо в вопрос, нажав кнопку "править"...